# Getting the wrong output (Ramanujan)

Tags: python-3.x, math, output, equation

Essentially what I want the function to do is this:

1. Take an integer input and save it as `n`
2. Print a list of vectors with two entries `(a,b)`, where [image: a^3+b^3=n]

For example, when I input `n = 443889`, I should get an output of `[(76,17),(38,73)]`, because the only two solutions to this problem are: [image: 46^3+17^3=443889], and [image: 38^3+73^3=443889]

But with my code, when I give the input `n=443889`, I get the output `[(76, 17), (75, 28), (74, 34), (73, 38), (72, 41)]`, even though some of these vectors doesn't give a solution to my equation.

```
def ramanujans(n):
    lista = []
    counter = 0

    for a in range(1,n):
        b = (n- (a**3))**(1/3)
        result = a**3 + b**3

        if isinstance(b,complex):
            break
        elif result == n:
            b = int(round(b))
            lista.insert(0,(a, b))

    return (lista)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a little different checking for complex results and a different check if `result == n` (integer comparison only) i seem to be getting the correct results:

```
def ramanujans(n):
    res = []

    for a in range(1, n):
        s = n - a**3
        if s < 0:
            break
        b = round(s**(1/3))
        result = a**3 + b**3

        if result == n:
            res.append((a, b))

    return res
```

with:

```
[(17, 76), (38, 73), (73, 38), (76, 17)]
```

as results for `n=443889`

you could stop the loop earlier; if `a` is around `(n/2)**(1/3)` you just get the results you already have with the `a` and `b` interchanged; this could then look like (did not carefully check the edge cases...):

```
from math import ceil

def ramanujans(n):

    res = []

    limit = ceil(((n/2)**(1/3)))

    for a in range(1, limit+1):
        s = n - a**3
        b = round(s**(1/3))
        result = a**3 + b**3
        if result == n:
            if a <= b:  # this is to cover the edge cases...
                res.append((a, b))
    return res

print(ramanujans(n=443889))  # [(17, 76), (38, 73)]
print(ramanujans(n=2000))    # [(10, 10)]
print(ramanujans(n=1729))    # [(1, 12), (9, 10)]
```

and would only return 'half' the results.

Comment: For some reason, the second code you posted does not work for n=2000. I should get the output [(10,10)], since 10^3+10^3=2000, but I get an empty list.

Comment: I tried changing to `ceil((n**(1/3))`, so I removed the `/2`-part. This makes it work for n = 2000, but it also makes the output to be doubled again for n = 1729.

Comment: Damn, I tried `ceil(((n/2)**(1/3)+1` with -1 and +0 aswell, I can't get it to work for both `n=2000` and `n=1729`.

Comment: actually there is no need to pre-calculate the `limit`; as soon as `a>b` (strict) you can stop.